# Increment function parameter value onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

### What I Require

I want to Increment function parameter value onclick in jquery.I have an input field which on button click creates a clone of itself. The field contains an onclick function. The default id of the text field is t1 and on each button click the id increments its numeric value ie: t2,t3,t4...... I am passing the numeric part as a parameter in my onclick function also. But I am not able to increment the parameter.

### Script (For incremeting the ids)

```
function fixIds(elem, cntr) {
   $(elem).find("[id]").add(elem).each(function() {
       this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + cntr;
   })
}


function addRow() {
 var count = parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10) + 1;
 var table = $('#matBody tr').first().clone();
 fixIds(table, count);
 table.appendTo('#matBody');

}
```

The count gives the value of previously added numeric value.

### HTML

```
<input type="button" id="add1" class="add" value="+" title="Add" onclick="addRow(1);"/>
```

Here I am able to increment the id from add1 to add2.... But I want the onclick parameter value also to be changed.

Comment: Make it gobal, will work it seems

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relationship between `fixIds` and `addRow`?

Comment: Sorry the fixIds is a function called from addRow

Comment: It would be great to see the content of `addRow` in this case. Unless it's a big mess inside :D

Comment: It seems that you don't need a parameter since you grab the value from a third party element (`#counter`). Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah the counter stores the last added value. if there are 4 rows added then the counter will be 4. If i click the 2 button the I need the value as 2.

Comment: So you want to bypass the value in `#counter` if there is a parameter provided right?

Comment: yeah thats what i want. the value will not depend on the counter value

Comment: Great. So, let's see what folks are able to suggest based on your last comment :) Go edit guys ;)

Comment: I'm not funny. Why not using an `if` to check the presence of this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value either from the id attr or you can add a custom data- attribute:

```
var addRow = function (event) {
    var value = event.target.id.split('add')[1];
    console.log(value);
}

document.getElementById('some-container').addEventListener('click', addRow);

<div id="some-container">
     <input type="button" id="add1" class="btn add1" value="+" title="Add"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to get the parameter of the clicked button. What if there are 4 buttons creted and the 3rd is clicked

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't get that right. So what you can do is inspect the event obj that is passed to the callback function, and extract the number from the id attribute for exaple

Comment: could you provide an example

Comment: In the above example i read the value from the id attribute; But you can use a custom attribute e.g. data-val="1". Basically, when you want to associate some data with a dom element, you can use the data-* attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultvalue = "t";
var defaultnumeric = 0;
$('#add1').click(function () {
 defaultnumeric = defaultnumeric + 1
 value = defaultvalue + defaultnumeric
 alert(value);
});

<input type="button" id="add1" class="add" value="+" title="Add" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aPTFH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var globalId = 1;

addRow = function (thisElem) {
 jQuery ("<input type='text' id='t" + (globalId ++) + "' />").insertAfter (thisElem);
    jQuery (thisElem).clone().appendTo ("body");
}
```

Using a global variable saves your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold needed index in `data-index` of each button.

## HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="add1" data-index="1" class="add" value="1+" title="Add"/>
</div>
```

## JavaScript:

```
function generateElement(index) {
    return $("<input />", {
        type: "button",
        class: "add",
        value: index + "+",
        title: "Add",
        "data-index": index
   });
}


$(document).on("click", ".add", function(e){
    var newIndex = Number($(this).attr("data-index")) + 1;
    var newElem = generateElement(newIndex);
    $("#container").append(newElem);
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/Bj6cb/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure to understand what you want, here is a guess :

```
function addRow(count) {
    if (!count) {
        count = parseInt($('#counter').val(), 10) + 1;
    }
    var table = $('#matBody tr').first().clone();
    fixIds(table, count);
    table.appendTo('#matBody');
}
```